# MySQL: Pacemaker cannot start the failed master as a new slave?

Tags: failover, high-availability, mysql-replication, pacemaker, corosync

- pacemaker-1.0.12-1
- corosync-1.2.7-1.1

I'm going to setup failover for MySQL replication (1 master and 1 slave)
follow this guide:
https://github.com/jayjanssen/Percona-Pacemaker-Resource-Agents/blob/master/doc/PRM-setup-guide.rst

Here're the output of **`crm configure show`**:

```
node serving-6192 \
    attributes p_mysql_mysql_master_IP="192.168.6.192"
node svr184R-638.localdomain \
    attributes p_mysql_mysql_master_IP="192.168.6.38"
primitive p_mysql ocf:percona:mysql \
    params config="/etc/my.cnf" pid="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid"
socket="/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock" replication_user="repl"
replication_passwd="x" test_user="test_user" test_passwd="x" \
    op monitor interval="5s" role="Master" OCF_CHECK_LEVEL="1" \
    op monitor interval="2s" role="Slave" timeout="30s"
OCF_CHECK_LEVEL="1" \
    op start interval="0" timeout="120s" \
    op stop interval="0" timeout="120s"
primitive writer_vip ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 \
    params ip="192.168.6.8" cidr_netmask="32" \
    op monitor interval="10s" \
    meta is-managed="true"
ms ms_MySQL p_mysql \
    meta master-max="1" master-node-max="1" clone-max="2"
clone-node-max="1" notify="true" globally-unique="false"
target-role="Master" is-managed="true"
colocation writer_vip_on_master inf: writer_vip ms_MySQL:Master
order ms_MySQL_promote_before_vip inf: ms_MySQL:promote writer_vip:start
property $id="cib-bootstrap-options" \
    dc-version="1.0.12-unknown" \
    cluster-infrastructure="openais" \
    expected-quorum-votes="2" \
    no-quorum-policy="ignore" \
    stonith-enabled="false" \
    last-lrm-refresh="1341801689"
property $id="mysql_replication" \
    p_mysql_REPL_INFO="192.168.6.192|mysql-bin.000006|338"
```

**`crm_mon`**:

```
Last updated: Mon Jul  9 10:30:01 2012
Stack: openais
Current DC: serving-6192 - partition with quorum
Version: 1.0.12-unknown
2 Nodes configured, 2 expected votes
2 Resources configured.
============

Online: [ serving-6192 svr184R-638.localdomain ]

 Master/Slave Set: ms_MySQL
     Masters: [ serving-6192 ]
     Slaves: [ svr184R-638.localdomain ]
writer_vip    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):    Started serving-6192
```

Editing `/etc/my.cnf` on the serving-6192 of wrong syntax to test
failover and it's working fine:

- svr184R-638.localdomain being promoted to become the master
- writer_vip switch to svr184R-638.localdomain

Current state:

```
Last updated: Mon Jul  9 10:35:57 2012
Stack: openais
Current DC: serving-6192 - partition with quorum
Version: 1.0.12-unknown
2 Nodes configured, 2 expected votes
2 Resources configured.
============

Online: [ serving-6192 svr184R-638.localdomain ]

 Master/Slave Set: ms_MySQL
     Masters: [ svr184R-638.localdomain ]
     Stopped: [ p_mysql:0 ]
writer_vip    (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):    Started svr184R-638.localdomain

Failed actions:
    p_mysql:0_monitor_5000 (node=serving-6192, call=15, rc=7,
status=complete): not running
    p_mysql:0_demote_0 (node=serving-6192, call=22, rc=7,
status=complete): not running
    p_mysql:0_start_0 (node=serving-6192, call=26, rc=-2, status=Timed
Out): unknown exec error
```

Remove the wrong syntax from `/etc/my.cnf` on serving-6192, and restart
`corosync`, what I would like to see is serving-6192 being started as a new
slave but it doesn't:

```
Failed actions:
    p_mysql:0_start_0 (node=serving-6192, call=4, rc=1,
status=complete): unknown error
```

Here're snippet of the logs which I'm suspecting:

```
Jul 09 10:46:32 serving-6192 lrmd: [7321]: info: rsc:p_mysql:0:4: start
Jul 09 10:46:32 serving-6192 lrmd: [7321]: info: RA output:
(p_mysql:0:start:stderr) Error performing operation: The
object/attribute does not exist

Jul 09 10:46:32 serving-6192 crm_attribute: [7420]: info: Invoked:
/usr/sbin/crm_attribute -N serving-6192 -l reboot --name readable -v 0
```

**`/var/log/cluster/corosync.log`**: http://fpaste.org/AyOZ/

The strange thing is I can starting it manually:

```
export OCF_ROOT=/usr/lib/ocf
export OCF_RESKEY_config="/etc/my.cnf"
export OCF_RESKEY_pid="/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid"
export OCF_RESKEY_socket="/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
export OCF_RESKEY_replication_user="repl"
export OCF_RESKEY_replication_passwd="x"
export OCF_RESKEY_test_user="test_user"
export OCF_RESKEY_test_passwd="x"
```

`sh -x /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/percona/mysql start`: http://fpaste.org/RVGh/

Did I make something wrong?

---

**Reply to @Patrick Fri Jul 13 10:22:10 ICT 2012:**

> I'm not sure why its failing as your log doesnt contain any messages
>   from the resource script (the ocf_log commands)

I take it all from `/var/log/cluster/corosync.log`. Have you got any reason in your mind?

**`/etc/corosync/corosync.conf`**

```
compatibility: whitetank

totem {
    version: 2
    secauth: off
    threads: 0
    interface {
        member {
            memberaddr: 192.168.6.192
        }
        member {
            memberaddr: 192.168.6.38
        }
        ringnumber: 0
        bindnetaddr: 192.168.6.0
        mcastaddr: 226.94.1.1
        mcastport: 5405
    }
}

logging {
    fileline: off
    to_stderr: yes
    to_logfile: yes
    to_syslog: yes
    logfile: /var/log/cluster/corosync.log
    debug: on
    timestamp: on
    logger_subsys {
        subsys: AMF
        debug: off
    }
}

amf {
    mode: disabled
}
```

> Also the reason the script works when you run it manually is because
>   you're not setting the variables which tells the script its a
>   master/slave resource. So when it runs, the script thinks its just a
>   single standalone instance.

Thanks. I've appended the following variables to my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_clone_max="2"
export OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_role="Slave"
```

Make it take effect `. ~/.bash_profile` and manually start mysql resource:

`sh -x /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/percona/mysql start`: http://fpaste.org/EMwa/

and it works fine:

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 192.168.6.38
                  Master_User: repl
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000072
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 1428602
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000006
                Relay_Log_Pos: 39370
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000072
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 1428602
              Relay_Log_Space: 39527
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 123
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Stop MySQL, turn on the debug, restart corosync, and here're the logs: http://fpaste.org/mZzS/

As you can see, nothing but 'unknown error':

```
 1.
    Jul 13 10:48:06 serving-6192 crmd: [3341]: debug:
    get_xpath_object: No match for
    //cib_update_result//diff-added//crm_config in
    /notify/cib_update_result/diff
 2.
    Jul 13 10:48:06 serving-6192 lrmd: [3338]: WARN: Managed
    p_mysql:1:start process 3416 exited with return code 1.
 3.
    Jul 13 10:48:06 serving-6192 crmd: [3341]: info:
    process_lrm_event: LRM operation p_mysql:1_start_0 (call=4,
    rc=1, cib-update=10, confirmed=true) unknown error
```

Any thoughts?

---

**UPDATE Sat Jul 14 17:16:03 ICT 2012:**

@Patrick: thank you for your tips!

The environment variables that Pacemaker uses as follow: http://fpaste.org/92yN/

As I suspected when chatting with you, the node `serving-6192` was started with the `OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_master_max=1`, therefore, due to the following code:

**`/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/percona/mysql:`**

```
if ocf_is_ms; then
    mysql_extra_params="--skip-slave-start"
fi
```

**`/usr/lib/ocf//lib/heartbeat/ocf-shellfuncs:`**

```
ocf_is_ms() {
    [ ! -z "${OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_master_max}" ] && [ "${OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_master_max}" -gt 0 ]
}
```

the extra param `--skip-slave-start` is included:

**`ps -ef | grep mysql`**

`root     18215     1  0 17:12 pts/4    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --skip-slave-start`

`mysql    19025 18215  1 17:12 pts/4    00:00:14 /usr/libexec/mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --skip-slave-start --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --open-files-limit=8192 --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --port=3306`

but SQL thread is still running:

```
         Slave_IO_Running: Yes
        Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
```

and replication is working fine.

`IFS=$'\n' ENV=( $(cat /tmp/16374.env) ); env -i - "${ENV[@]}" sh -x /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/percona/mysql start`: http://fpaste.org/x7xE/

I am hitting my head against the wall (: -> |

Comment: I'm not sure why its failing as your log doesnt contain any messages from the resource script (the ocf_log commands). However the `crm_attribute` error is because the script is broken and is setting a non-existent attribute (it's non-fatal though). Also the reason the script works when you run it manually is because you're not setting the variables which tells the script its a master/slave resource. So when it runs, the script thinks its just a single standalone instance. And since this works, that indicates the error is likely when it tries to go into slave mode.

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not logging. Not saying you did something wrong, just makes no sense. The next step I'd take is to fully duplicate the environment. Edit `/usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/percona/mysql` and add `env > /tmp/$$.env`. Then have the script fail again, and in the log look for `WARN: Managed p_mysql:1:start process XXXX exited with return code 1`. Then do `IFS=$'\n' ENV=( $(cat /tmp/XXXX.env) ); env -i - "${ENV[@]}" sh -x /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/percona/mysql start` (replacing XXXX with the pid from the log). This will give you the **exact** same environment the script runs with.

Comment: @Patrick: updated again.

Comment: Do not, under any circumstances, define OCF_RESKEY_ variables in your shell's profile. These are set for you when you configure properties for the resource in the cluster configuration. That you need to set them indicates your config is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eureka!

Both of us forgot a **very** very important log file, it's... `/var/log/mysqld.log`:

```
socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Atomicorp
[Note] Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'mysql-bin.000082' at position 58569, relay log './mysqld-relay-bin.000002' position: 58715
[Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master 'repl@192.168.6.38:3306',replication started in log 'mysql-bin.000082' at position 58569
[Warning] Aborted connection 10 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'test_user' host: 'localhost' (init_connect command failed)
[Warning] The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
[Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown
```

As you can guess, I tracked the user activity by combining the binlog and [`init-connect`](http://www.goitworld.com/mysql-audit-access-log-records/):

`init_connect = "INSERT INTO audit.accesslog (connect_time, user_host, connection_id) VALUES (NOW(), CURRENT_USER(), CONNECTION_ID());"`

but `serving-6192` is set read-only when starting as a slave, and then when Pacemaker perform monitor operation with `test_user`:

```
    # Check for test table
    ocf_run -q $MYSQL $MYSQL_OPTIONS_TEST \
        -e "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $OCF_RESKEY_test_table"
```

`init_connect` command failed with the above error:

> The MySQL server is running with the `--read-only` option so it cannot
>   execute this statement

The solution is I should set the `init_connect` option to the empty string before initializing the monitor action (don't forget to turn it back when promoting a node to become a master)

To anyone who are using [event scheduler](http://palominodb.com/blog/2010/11/08/events-and-replication-part-1): also note that you must turn it on when promoting a slave to become a master:

```
set_event_scheduler() {
    local es_val
    if ocf_is_true $1; then
        es_val="on"
    else
        es_val="off"
    fi
    ocf_run $MYSQL $MYSQL_OPTIONS_REPL \
        -e "SET GLOBAL event_scheduler=${es_val}"
}

get_event_scheduler() {
    # Check if event-scheduler is set
    local event_scheduler_state

    event_scheduler_state=`$MYSQL $MYSQL_OPTIONS_REPL \
        -e "SHOW VARIABLES" | grep event_scheduler | awk '{print $2}'`

    if [ "$event_scheduler_state" = "ON" ]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

mysql_promote() {
    local master_info

    if ( ! mysql_status err ); then
        return $OCF_NOT_RUNNING
    fi
    ocf_run $MYSQL $MYSQL_OPTIONS_REPL \
        -e "STOP SLAVE"

    # Set Master Info in CIB, cluster level attribute
    update_data_master_status
    master_info="$(get_local_ip)|$(get_master_status File)|$(get_master_status Position)"
    ${CRM_ATTR_REPL_INFO} -v "$master_info"
    rm -f $tmpfile

    set_read_only off || return $OCF_ERR_GENERIC
    set_event_scheduler on || return $OCF_ERR_GENERIC
```

Also don't forget to turn it off when demoting:

```
    'pre-demote')
        # Is the notification for our set
        notify_resource=`echo $OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_notify_demote_resource|cut -d: -f1`
        my_resource=`echo $OCF_RESOURCE_INSTANCE|cut -d: -f1`
        if [ $notify_resource != ${my_resource} ]; then
            ocf_log debug "Notification is not for us"
            return $OCF_SUCCESS
        fi

        demote_host=`echo $OCF_RESKEY_CRM_meta_notify_demote_uname|tr -d " "`
        if [ $demote_host = ${HOSTNAME} ]; then
            ocf_log info "post-demote notification for $demote_host"
            set_read_only on
            set_event_scheduler off
```

Cheers,